# Resolution issue in WinRT

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, scrollviewer

I have a dashboard that using scrollviewer in my WinRT project and its all of xaml codes are dynamic but it seems great in 1920x1080. My problem is is works correctly in 1920x1080 but it is not fit into tablet pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if you're actually shooting for RT then you're looking more at 1366x768, you can either make it for that, or a quick workaround might be to just embed your `ScrollViewer` outermost child in a `ViewBox` for now. Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try it 9 hours later and answer you. Thank you @Chris W.